# Python CSV file - How to remove data from CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've got problem when i was practicing knowledge of CSV files in Python. I wrote few functions like reading from CSV file, adding new data in to existing CSV file and now i would like to add function allowing user to remove some of data from CSV file. My function of to add new data looks like this:

```
def writein():
    with open('employee data.csv', 'a') as employeeData:
        writeby = csv.writer(employeeData, delimiter = ',')
        writeNEN = input('Enter the name of the new employee: \n')
        writeNESN = input('Enter the surname of the new employee: \n')
        writeNEP = input('Enter the position of the new employee: \n')
        writeNEBD = input('Enter the date of birth of the new employee: \n')
        writeby.writerow([writeNEN, writeNESN, writeNEP, writeNEBD])
```

Now i would like to make the same function but instead of adding i want to remove existing data. I was tried this:

```
def dataremove():
    with open('employee data.csv', 'r') as employeeData:
        removewith = csv.remover(employeeData, delimiter = ',')
```

But there is no attribute like 'remove' or 'delete' in csv modul.

How can i write function allowing to remove few of datas?

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no such thing as "removing" data from files in computers.  You can only delete an entire file, truncate a file to delete some amount from the end, or read the old content, edit it in memory, and write it to a new file.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use `csv.reader` to load the data, edit it as needed, then use `csv.writer` as you have now.

Comment: So for example I can make function reading CSV file, then I can replace existing data with like empty line using csv.writer?

Comment: @ArtFiNCH: Sure.

Comment: Instead of replacing it with an empty line, just skip writing anything in its place.

Answer (score 0):

To delete some rows you should read all the file, remove the rows that you don't want (you can use `filter` to do this for example on the list of rows), then rewrite all the csv file.
I suggest you to use the `pandas` library to do this operation, maybe is overkill to do this but simplifies a lot this operation

```
import pandas as pd
def writein():
        df = pd.read_csv('employee data.csv')
        writeNEN = input('Enter the name of the new employee: \n')
        writeNESN = input('Enter the surname of the new employee: \n')
        writeNEP = input('Enter the position of the new employee: \n')
        writeNEBD = input('Enter the date of birth of the new employee: \n')
        df.append([writeNEN, writeNESN, writeNEP, writeNEBD])
        df.to_csv('employee data.csv', index=False)

def delete():
        df = pd.read_csv('employee data.csv')
        df = df[~df.name.str.startswith('N')] #keep the names that don't start with N
        df.to_csv('employee data.csv', index=False)
```